# Two sed commands in one command

Tags: sed

I have a file with a lots of names etc. and with spaces in between. Now, I want to delete all trailing spaces and all empty lines in this file with sed.

I have two commands for this task but I would like to have a combination of both:

```
sed -i's/\s*$//g' 
sed -i'/^$/d'
```

Comment: You mean `sed -i 's/.../.../;/^$/d'`?

Comment: `sed -ne '/[^  ]/s/ *$//p'`

Answer (score 9):

With GNU `sed` (and probably others), you can give multiple commands separated by a semicolon:

```
sed -i 's/\s*$//g; /^$/d'
```

Other `sed` implementations might need you to give the two commands separately with `-e`:

```
sed -i -e 's/\s*$//g' -e '/^$/d'
```

Finally, you could also combine them into a `sed` script:

```
$ cat foo.sed
s/\s*$//g
/^$/d
```

Then, you run it with `-f`:

```
$ sed -i -f foo.sed file
```

Answer (score 2):

this is the command you are looking for:

```sh
sed -ne '/[^ ]/s/ *$//p' <in >out
```

... for lines which match at least least 1 not-space character, `sed` will susbstitute away the longest match it can make of 0 or more trailing spaces on the tail of the line. if successful *(and it always will be, because there's never a shortage of nothing)*, the line is `p`rinted.

the result is that command `p`rints only not-space and not-blank lines while simultaneously trimming all trailing spaces.